# Find date for last four sundays

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

Namely what I need is:

The key over here is that it does change the dates every week, from last Sunday, to 2nd last Sunday and so on, so that it is dynamic.

Will appreciate if someone can help.

```
CASE
  WHEN f.[STARTDATE] = last week Sunday (03/06) THEN '1 week ago'
  WHEN f.[STARTDATE] = last 2 week Sunday (02/27) THEN '2 weeks ago'
  WHEN f.[STARTDATE] = last 3 week Sunday (02/20) THEN '3 week ago'
  WHEN f.[STARTDATE] = last 4 week Sunday (02/13) THEN '4 week ago'
END AS 'STARTDATE'
```

Thank you

Comment: Which SQL platform are you using? It's customary to add the specific tag for that platform (e.g. Microsoft SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc) It's important to know this because most deal with dates slightly differently.

Comment: @David784 SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio).

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: FYI SSMS is only a client interface - the database you are using is SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get nearest Sunday before you can subtract 7, 14, 21 and 28 days from it. The simplest way is to check current day of week and calculate an offset: 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday and so on:

```
with cte as (
    select offsett = case datename(weekday, cast(current_timestamp as date))
        when 'sunday'    then 0
        when 'monday'    then 1
        when 'tuesday'   then 2
        when 'wednesday' then 3
        when 'thursday'  then 4
        when 'friday'    then 5
        when 'saturday'  then 6
    end
)
select case
    when f.[startdate] = dateadd(day, -cte.offsett -  7, cast(current_timestamp as date)) then '1 week ago'
    when f.[startdate] = dateadd(day, -cte.offsett - 14, cast(current_timestamp as date)) then '2 week ago'
    when f.[startdate] = dateadd(day, -cte.offsett - 21, cast(current_timestamp as date)) then '1 week ago'
    when f.[startdate] = dateadd(day, -cte.offsett - 28, cast(current_timestamp as date)) then '2 week ago'
end
from f
cross join cte
```